# Does an asteroid field event affects the 'Tactical Approach' achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

While trying to achieve the 'Tactical Approach' achievement, I've encountered with the below event (see picture).

> Scans reveal a large asteroid field nearby. Short-range scanners may
>   discover useful materials while we wait for the FTL to recharge.

If I attend this event, will it affect the 'Tactical Approach' achievement?
[image]

Comment: BTW - This happened more than once in the game, so keep in mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Approach

> It also seems that any "normal" beacon where you choose to, for
>   example, explore an asteroid field, will cause you to fail the
>   achievement.

It goes into more detail about other failure events but this suggests that if you choose to explore you will fail the achievement but if you ignore it that it won't.